# How to have a model method get(index) like the one of `ListView`

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

In QML when we have a `ListModel` this model has a method: `get(index)` which returns an Object with one property per role, named after the rolename. The nice thing about this object is, **that changes of those properties are propagated back to the model**.

Now I have a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which can be - with minor changes to support `strings` as role identifiers, rather than numbers - registered as QML type.
The problem: I don't know how to write a method, similar to `ListModel.get(index)`. So far I only iterated over my roles, and stuffed the `data(index, role)` into a `QMap<QString, QVariant>` (results in a JS Object in QML).

*I know the* `roleNames` *only at runtime*, so I can't use a hardcoded Class with `Q_PROPERTY`'s for each `roleName`. I think `ListView` uses some descendant of [`QAbstractDynamicMetaObject`](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/dc/ddd/struct_q_abstract_dynamic_meta_object.html), called [`ModelNodeMetaObject`](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/dd/dcd/class_model_node_meta_object.html) for this, but I only found an old piece of `Qt4`-"Documentation" that mentioned it.

I'd like to have a similar construct for my `QSortFilterProxyModel` and possibly other models as well. So far I circumvent the problem by forwarding the call `get(index)` to `get(sourceIndex(index))` but this only works as long as the `sourceModel` is a `ListModel`, so it is no desirable solution.

So the question is:

- How can I use a `QAbstractDynamicMetaObject` to have a `get(index)`-function similar to a QML `ListModel`

Comment: You may be interested by my library : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/ . It has a `get(index)` method but unfortunately it doesn't propagate modifications back to the model.

Comment: I already know your `SortFilterProxyModel`, but you have the same `get`-function as I, and therefore it does not solve my problem.

Comment: It doesn't indeed, but if you were not aware of it it might help you for the rest. That feature has been on my radar, I need to take some time to analyse it. Or maybe you can do a PR ;)

Comment: Indeed your solution has quite some nice features, and I think analyzing your code will teach me plenty! I hope at some point someone finds a solution to solve the `get`-function

Answer (score 0):

I think building a meta object at runtime requires private API, i.e. `QMetaObjectBuilder`.

You could try if QML can also access dynamic properties of a `QObject`.
Create a `QObject` instance and set your values with `QObject::setProperty()` instead of adding them to a variant map.

Another option for changing model data is to go for a get/set approach like C++ does.
E.g. a `set` method that takes an index and a variant map.

Comment: I already have the equivalent to `ListModel`'s `setProperty(index, property, value)`, but as I am moving from multiple `ListModel`s to few that are then accessed through `SortFilterProxyModel`s, and the `ListModel`s might be replaced through completly custom models, it would have been convenient to not have all the `get(index).propertyName = newValue` replaced by `setProperty(index, propertyName, newValue)` though it is only... a minor issue. If I had found an easy solution I would have written a wrapper like a `QMLifyProxyModel` to provide a convenient QML interface to all QAbstractItemModels

Comment: So the option with the dynamic properties does not work?

Comment: I have not managed to get it working so far, but I can't say that it does not work because it can't work, or due to my stupidity. As soon as I managed to get it working with your solution, I will accept your answer.

Comment: It seems not to be working: in test.cpp: `QObject *Test::test() { QObject *m = new QObject(this); m->setProperty("test1", QVariant(5)); printf(m->property("test1").toByteArray()); return m; }`; in main.qml: `Test { Component.onCompleted: console.log(JSON.stringify(test()), test().test1)` shows only a `objectName` but no property `test1`. In C++ it has the desired property.